# Python : Multiprocessing with a huge dataframe is pretty slow

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, dataframe, multiprocessing

I am doing data analysis of a particle physics experiment. I have a huge dataframe with millions of lines. Below is an example of the dataframe structure :

```
      n_events  event_number  channel                                                  t                                                  v
0          200             0      1.0  [0.0, 0.292229, 0.44511900000000004, 0.686493,...  [0.007145071463695994, 0.006022061677328001, 0...
1          200             0      2.0  [0.0, 0.28361, 0.43580699999999994, 0.70387699...  [-0.004745911500159997, -0.004473575244724004,...
2          200             0      3.0  [0.0, 0.290339, 0.44740100000000005, 0.700787,...  [-0.0016976513865119857, -0.000588632718491007...
3          200             0      4.0  [0.0, 0.299564, 0.435033, 0.701605, 0.7830996,...  [0.000518971074000005, 0.0015031308265279996, ...
4          200             0      5.0  [0.0, 0.295462, 0.43185, 0.689991, 0.804407, 1...  [-0.012224856444671991, -0.012481382646527987,...
...        ...           ...      ...                                                ...                                                ...
7195       200           199     29.0  [0.0, 0.273977, 0.394305, 0.64364, 0.781702, 1...  [-0.006007219163999997, -0.006066839886615997,...
7196       200           199     30.0  [0.0, 0.296464, 0.408051, 0.660629, 0.797999, ...  [-0.0071352449638400085, -0.007720353590299007...
7197       200           199     31.0  [0.0, 0.271873, 0.39696299999999995, 0.661967,...  [0.0007936306725499976, 0.0006720786866000081,...
7198       200           199     32.0  [0.0, 0.274194, 0.390268, 0.652645, 0.794755, ...  [0.008792689244320001, 0.008201458288511989, 0...
7199       200           199     36.0  [0.0, 0.281648, 0.402901, 0.656489, 0.793202, ...  [0.9035749247410491, 0.899703268236, 0.8972429...


    n_events  event_number  channel                                                  t                                                  v
0        200             0      1.0  [0.0, 0.292229, 0.44511900000000004, 0.686493,...  [0.007145071463695994, 0.006022061677328001, 0...
1        200             0      2.0  [0.0, 0.28361, 0.43580699999999994, 0.70387699...  [-0.004745911500159997, -0.004473575244724004,...
2        200             0      3.0  [0.0, 0.290339, 0.44740100000000005, 0.700787,...  [-0.0016976513865119857, -0.000588632718491007...
3        200             0      4.0  [0.0, 0.299564, 0.435033, 0.701605, 0.7830996,...  [0.000518971074000005, 0.0015031308265279996, ...
4        200             0      5.0  [0.0, 0.295462, 0.43185, 0.689991, 0.804407, 1...  [-0.012224856444671991, -0.012481382646527987,...
5        200             0      6.0  [0.0, 0.304114, 0.431968, 0.6919690000000001, ...  [-0.006504729964460993, -0.006973892963776013,...
6        200             0      7.0  [0.0, 0.296276, 0.435403, 0.694577, 0.801506, ...  [0.0076502175278079804, 0.007291070848924005, ...
7        200             0      8.0  [0.0, 0.302246, 0.43909600000000004, 0.707817,...  [0.005709271868173, 0.005525502225727999, 0.00...
8        200             0     33.0  [0.0, 0.312825, 0.450079, 0.7171700000000001, ...  [0.6907829934142, 0.65032811641518, 0.63168262...
9        200             0      9.0  [0.0, 0.162366, 0.41691300000000003, 0.546435,...  [-0.004370937556799992, -0.004156079620345007,...
10       200             0     10.0  [0.0, 0.168124, 0.430847, 0.551334, 0.810323, ...  [0.005713839258880994, 0.005151084024971997, 0...
11       200             0     11.0  [0.0, 0.166088, 0.43300900000000003, 0.5373290...  [-0.006496423078124987, -0.0059013241952349995...
12       200             0     12.0  [0.0, 0.133375, 0.4204, 0.521838, 0.803831, 0....  [-0.0029161667740250116, -0.004175291108256005...
13       200             0     13.0  [0.0, 0.126736, 0.425956, 0.530385, 0.811472, ...  [-0.0045837650761579906, -0.003585277339199997...
14       200             0     14.0  [0.0, 0.134787, 0.419325, 0.527267, 0.808555, ...  [-0.001530516654803007, -0.0011034030005499943...
15       200             0     15.0  [0.0, 0.1509, 0.444928, 0.5294964, 0.8145954, ...  [-0.00559784605927201, -0.004645566291229007, ...
16       200             0     16.0  [0.0, 0.134896, 0.422334, 0.538761, 0.81445200...  [0.009337214123531992, 0.009593533354463982, 0...
17       200             0     34.0  [0.0, 0.13378, 0.409487, 0.528365, 0.791995, 0...  [0.809813636495625, 0.7967833234162501, 0.7681...
18       200             0     17.0  [0.0, 0.240012, 0.402098, 0.6908080000000001, ...  [-0.002736104546672001, -0.0034600646495999824...
19       200             0     18.0  [0.0, 0.256932, 0.40772600000000003, 0.694829,...  [-0.004761098550782997, -0.004992603885120003,...
20       200             0     19.0  [0.0, 0.260573, 0.411907, 0.7032830000000001, ...  [-0.0020984008527860022, -0.001233839987092994...
21       200             0     20.0  [0.0, 0.260196, 0.395066, 0.7063619999999999, ...  [0.005039756488365984, 0.006215568753132001, 0...
22       200             0     21.0  [0.0, 0.26385, 0.377695, 0.690218, 0.792184, 1...  [0.0012567172712239978, 0.0017176489079889995,...
23       200             0     22.0  [0.0, 0.281995, 0.414246, 0.7113590000000001, ...  [-0.004021068645631988, -0.0038137520037749995...
24       200             0     23.0  [0.0, 0.274982, 0.39725, 0.7177819999999999, 0...  [0.00020083088635199054, -7.622279512499036e-0...
25       200             0     24.0  [0.0, 0.26048, 0.37926099999999996, 0.71315, 0...  [0.015447624570974998, 0.015128326144224, 0.01...
26       200             0     35.0  [0.0, 0.260156, 0.404854, 0.6990419999999999, ...  [0.826655732310342, 0.8016246495956479, 0.7899...
27       200             0     25.0  [0.0, 0.161695, 0.420327, 0.576986, 0.853091, ...  [-0.01176219648990401, -0.011605116890357987, ...
28       200             0     26.0  [0.0, 0.142957, 0.414581, 0.5652809999999999, ...  [-0.00017965899878400054, 0.000329458201304994...
29       200             0     27.0  [0.0, 0.151938, 0.42064199999999996, 0.544481,...  [-0.012079087800160012, -0.011521835995015996,...
30       200             0     28.0  [0.0, 0.133352, 0.41161899999999996, 0.53848, ...  [-0.005415268565248003, -0.0057859392168489975...
31       200             0     29.0  [0.0, 0.126623, 0.41861800000000005, 0.545479,...  [-0.012657557405900003, -0.012799759762259007,...
32       200             0     30.0  [0.0, 0.117088, 0.41099399999999997, 0.55351, ...  [-0.013853044528840005, -0.013165832426528, -0...
33       200             0     31.0  [0.0, 0.138599, 0.425755, 0.531386, 0.830847, ...  [-0.005198338900159984, -0.006477930675, -0.00...
34       200             0     32.0  [0.0, 0.128048, 0.389703, 0.548266, 0.835658, ...  [0.004916808473749997, 0.005265623096212002, 0...
35       200             0     36.0  [0.0, 0.129798, 0.41002700000000003, 0.551741,...  [0.8577803214022401, 0.84971873621071, 0.82866...
```

The first step is to reduce the data and keep only the events with signals. We consider a signal when we have a value greater than 0.05 in one of the rows in the "v" column. Each event has 36 channels. If in these 36 channels we have at least one signal, we keep all channels related to this event, so we keep this event. However, if no signal is detected in the 36 channels of an event, I remove the event from the dataframe completely.

I have written a function that does this part. In order to reduce the computation time, I would like to use multiprocessing. I have first divided the dataframe into 10 parts because I would like to use 10 threads. Obviously, the sub part of the dataframe will always contain the whole event. The events cannot be split into two separate subparts.

```
def keep_event_data(dataframe, limit) :

    events = list(set(dataframe["event_number"]))
    list_keep_event = []

    for k in events :

        df_reduce = dataframe[dataframe["event_number"]==k].reset_index(drop=True)

        # WE START THE LOOP IN THE WHOLE DATAFRAME
        for j in df_reduce.index :

            if any(n > limit for n in df_reduce.loc[j, Col_tension]) :
    
                list_keep_event.append(k)
                break
            
            else :

                pass

    return list_keep_event


def split_dataframe(dataframe, pool) :

    max_event = dataframe["event_number"].max()

    # Split the dataframe into a list
    range_iter = range(max_event+1)
    range_split = np.array_split(range_iter, pool)

    list_df = []

    for j in range_split :

        list_df.append(dataframe[dataframe["event_number"].isin(j)])

    return list_df


if __name__ == '__main__':

    df = some_value

    # SPLIT TH DATAFRAME 
    df_split = split_dataframe(dataframe=df, pool=nb_pool)


    func = partial(keep_event_data, limit=limit_tension)

    pool = Pool(nb_pool)
    res = pool.map(func, df_split)
    list_event_keep = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(res))
    df = df[df["event_number"].isin(list_event_keep)]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

By using map of the multiprocessing library, the time becomes longer. I observe that it uses more memory around 10 Gb of RAM and the CPU does not seem to be used. How can I fix this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: porcesses don't share data in memory - so it has to save data on disk, starts process which  reads data from disk. And after calculations it saves data on disk and main process reads it from disk. For big data it can be problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! What do you recommend? What should I change ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you could try is to "lazily" evaluate as much as possible to reduce storage requirements. This means substituting method `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap` for `multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map` and using generator functions and expressions wherever possible.

If you are running on a platform that uses `spawn` to create new processes, such as Windows (by the way, you are supposed to tag multiplatform question with the platform you *are* running under), your creation of the initial dataframe should not be at global scope but done within the `if __name__ == "__main__" :` block either inline or via a function call. If the code is at global scope, it will be executed by every process in the multiprocessing pool as part of its initialization requiring lots of CPU and memory resources.

The following code uses a special class, `BoundedQueueProcessPool`, whose `imap` method will prevent the *iterable* argument from generating its elements faster than can be processed by the worker function. This should have a positive affect on memory usage.

```py
import multiprocessing.pool
import multiprocessing

class ImapResult():
    def __init__(self, semaphore, result):
        self._semaphore = semaphore
        self.it = result.__iter__()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        try:
            elem = self.it.__next__()
            self._semaphore.release()
            return elem
        except StopIteration:
            raise
        except:
            self._semaphore.release()
            raise

class BoundedQueuePool:
    def __init__(self, limit, semaphore):
        self._limit = limit
        self._semaphore = semaphore

    def release(self, result, callback=None):
        self._semaphore.release()
        if callback:
            callback(result)

    def apply_async(self, func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None, error_callback=None):
        self._semaphore.acquire()
        callback_fn = self.release if callback is None else lambda result: self.release(result, callback=callback)
        error_callback_fn = self.release if error_callback is None else lambda result: self.release(result, callback=callback)
        return super().apply_async(func, args, kwds, callback=callback_fn, error_callback=error_callback_fn)

    def imap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):
        def new_iterable(iterable):
            for elem in iterable:
                self._semaphore.acquire()
                yield elem
        if chunksize > self._limit:
            raise ValueError(f'chunksize argument exceeds {self._limit}')
        result = super().imap(func, new_iterable(iterable), chunksize)
        return ImapResult(self._semaphore, result)

    def imap_unordered(self, func, iterable, chunksize=1):
        def new_iterable(iterable):
            for elem in iterable:
                self._semaphore.acquire()
                yield elem
        if chunksize > self._limit:
            raise ValueError(f'chunksize argument exceeds {self._limit}')
        result = super().imap_unordered(func, new_iterable(iterable), chunksize)
        return ImapResult(self._semaphore, result)

class BoundedQueueProcessPool(BoundedQueuePool, multiprocessing.pool.Pool):
    def __init__(self, *args, max_waiting_tasks=None, **kwargs):
        multiprocessing.pool.Pool.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        if max_waiting_tasks is None:
            max_waiting_tasks = self._processes
        elif max_waiting_tasks < 0:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid negative max_waiting_tasks value: {max_waiting_tasks}')
        limit = self._processes + max_waiting_tasks
        BoundedQueuePool.__init__(self, limit, multiprocessing.BoundedSemaphore(limit))

N_CHUNKS = 1_000

def split(lst, n):
    k, m = divmod(len(lst), n)
    return (lst[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n))

def split_dataframe(dataframe):
    # Split the dataframe into a list
    range_iter = range(len(dataframe.index))
    # This will return a generator expression that generates ranges rather
    # than arrays for potentially a big savings:
    range_split = split(range_iter, N_CHUNKS)
    for r in range_split:
        yield dataframe[r.start:r.stop]


if __name__ == "__main__" :

    dataframe = some_value

    func = partial(keep_event_data, limit=limit_tension)

    pool = BoundedQueueProcessPool(nb_pool)
    # Use chunksize of 1:
    res = pool.imap(func, split_dataframe(dataframe))
    df = pd.concat(res, ignore_index=True)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

**But there is no getting around the fact that there will always be considerable overhead in serializing/de-serializing the dataframes from one address space to another. Multiprocessing will only reduce the running time if your worker function `keep_event_data` is sufficiently CPU-intensive to justify that additional overhead.**

Comment: Hi @Booboo,
Thank's for your answer and the time that you took to answer me. I tried your solution and unfotunately it did not decrease the time. It uses only memory and not my CPU. I have modified my function to use less memory. However it is still not good

Comment: I think one problem is that you are only breaking up the very large dataframe consisting of "millions of lines" into `nb_pool` chunks, which are still very large chunks taking lots of memory. I have updated the answer to break up the dataframe into `N_CHUNKS` pieces where I have set `N_CHUNKS` to 1000. I am not sure what "millions" means. Maybe `N_CHUNKS` should be 10_000. If you have 1,000,000 rows in your data frame, then with `N_CHUNKS` as 1000, we will be passing to your worker function dataframes with 1000 rows. (more...)

Comment: However, because of the *chunksize* argument,  *chunksize* tasks will be batched together and passed to each process in the pool utilizing more memory but resulting in fewer transfers. So it might be best to use a chunksize value of 1, which is what you get if you do not specify the *chunksize* argument.

Comment: I will have a better solution in a few moments.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It works ! My first script where I did not use multiproccessing did it in 2min30s and with your code it does in 48s on a set of 360'000 rows (it is around 5% of all my dataset). Can I ask you a link to a website where I can understand what you write in your code :). Because it is indeed powerfull

Comment: I don't understand what you want a link to. You can look up the documentation on how `imap` work in general. And this particular implementation of `imap` wraps your passed *iterable* conceptually incrementing a counter every time it submits to the pool a new task and decrements the counter every time a new result is returned but will halt submitting new tasks once that counter reaches a maximum. (more...)

Comment: As I said that is what it does conceptually, this is implemented using a `multiprocessing.BlockingSemaphore` initialized by default to twice the pool size so that when a process in the pool finishes processing a task there should always be a task in the queue for it to work on. This uses a bit more memory but reduces elapsed time. If my answer ultimately satisfies your question, then you should *accept* the answer when you are comfortable doing so.